# Airflow skipping subdags' tasks during scheduled run

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a DAG that runs well when triggered manually from the Web UI, but on the scheduled daily run all subdag are marked as success after 60 seconds and all the tasks inside those subdags are skipped.

Why are the tasks skipped on a scheduled run?

**MainDag:**

```py
with models.DAG(
    "MainDag",
    schedule_interval='@daily',
    start_date=dates.days_ago(0),
    user_defined_macros=TEMPLATE_ENV,
) as dag:

    prepare_factory = SubDagOperator(
        task_id="prepare_factory ",
        trigger_rule="one_success",
        subdag=subdag_prepare_factory.sub_dag(
            dag.dag_id, "prepare_factory", dag.start_date, dag.schedule_interval
        ),
    )
```

**SubDag:**

```py
def sub_dag(parent_dag_name, child_dag_name, start_date, schedule_interval):
    with models.DAG(
            "{0}.{1}".format(parent_dag_name, child_dag_name),
            schedule_interval=schedule_interval,
            start_date=start_date,
            user_defined_macros=TEMPLATE_ENV,
    ) as dag:

        # HOOKS
        hook = _sshHook.getSshHook()

        # Tasks
        step_1 = ssh_operator.SSHOperator(
            task_id="step_1",
            ssh_hook=hook,
            command="script.sh"),
        )
```

[image: Parent Dag view]

[image: SubDag view]

Comment: could you share your dag config? what is the start_date?

Comment: The start_date is *dates.days_ago(0)*.

I will add DAG config to my question

Comment: I highly recommend not using SubDags in new dags on Airflow2. The feature will be deprecated.

Comment: Arf. To be honest I was migrating from Oozie and using google's o2a library.

There is no problem in maintaining a huge dag in one place? (> 50 tasks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the start_date. Using `date.days_ago`was creating error between the main dag and the subdags at midnight.

I'm now using a static date with `datetime`

**Example with static date**

```
with models.DAG(
    "MainDag",
    schedule_interval='30 0 * * *',
    start_date=datetime(2021, 4, 7),
    user_defined_macros=TEMPLATE_ENV,
) as dag:
```